# Change button style on page load

Tags: c#, database, button, styles

This is my table and on this table I have cells in form of buttons. With my css sheet I have made them green.

```
<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" BorderWidth="2px" BorderColor="#0033cc" BackColor="#ffcccc" >

            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell CssClass="Table-cell-room" ID="D256">D256<br /></asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell><asp:Button runat="server" Width="100px" Text="Boka" ID="R1B1" OnClick="Button_Click_First_Row" CssClass="Buttons"/></asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell><asp:Button runat="server" Width="100px" Text="Boka" ID="R1B2" OnClick="Button_Click_First_Row" CssClass="Buttons"/></asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell><asp:Button runat="server" Width="100px" Text="Boka" ID="R1B3" OnClick="Button_Click_First_Row" CssClass="Buttons"/></asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell><asp:Button runat="server" Width="100px" Text="Boka" ID="R1B4" OnClick="Button_Click_First_Row" CssClass="Buttons"/></asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell><asp:Button runat="server" Width="100px" Text="Boka" ID="R1B5" OnClick="Button_Click_First_Row" CssClass="Buttons"/></asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
```

I have also a Database table called `Room` and contains Id, Button_id and CheckIfBooked.
Now I want to use my "colum" CheckedIfBook to see if they are booked, meaning CheckedIfBooked = 1.

All of this work but I have no idea to style my buttons on the table which of those who already have CheckedIfBooked = 1.

Meaning that in my Database table I have R1B1 and it's value CheckedIfBooked = 1. But I have no idea to code this in page load. Also I don't want to use

```
if(Button_id == R1B2){
  CheckedIfBooked == 1
  //Do some styling on that button
}
```

Cause I have ALOT of buttons and in my c# code I use sender as new button to get the correct ID from the button clicked.

Comment: You ok with using javascript/jquery to style these buttons, or are you looking for a c#-only solution?

Comment: Well I rather just use c# at this moment, but it's not required so if you have anything please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Possible Solution #1

When rendering the page, add an additional css class to your button if `isBooked = true`

```
if (isBooked) {
  /// Render the "isBooked" TableCell Button 
  <asp:TableCell> ... CssClass="isBooked"/></asp:TableCell>  
} else {
  /// Render the "not Booked" TableCell Button 
  <asp:TableCell> ... CssClass="Button"/></asp:TableCell> 
}
```

Then in your css:

```
.isBooked { /* isBooked Button Styles Here */ }
```

So when your code gets rendered to HTML, the css classes are already in place:

```
<!-- Example HTML Output -->
< ... class="Button"   ... ></>
< ... class="isBooked" ... ></>
< ... class="Button"   ... ></>
```

### Possible Solution #2

On page load, have jQuery look for the booked buttons, and disable them, or style them, etc..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("isBooked").each(function(index){
        // each isBooked element is now available via $(this)
        $(this).addClass("bookedButton");
        $(this).prop("disabled", true);
        // ...
    });
});
```

**Security note:** Simply disabling a form button on the client-side (via javascript) isn't enough, you also need to validate data on the server side. So if you disable form elements on the client, make sure your server also verifies that nothing "booked" is trying to be submitted to your form.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So you mean check first which of my buttons in the table that have CheckedIfBooked = 1, and all of those who have that value I shall change cssclass on and use the style from that?

Comment: Yes, that would be the main idea. You can't target a form element to style them unless you give it something to target with, like a unique class name "bookedButton" or something similar.

Comment: My "Possible Solution #1" is the most straightforward out of the two options. So when you are rendering the page HTML, simply run your check `checkIfBooked`, and if "true" apply some unique value to the TableCell that your css can find. Then the styling will be handled automatically for you when the page renders.

Comment: Yeah sure this make sense but how can I change the CssClass = Buttons to Yours CssClass = bookedButton ?

Comment: AS you can see in the updated example code...basically, you do the isBooked check on the server for each button, and assign the css value to the TableCell/Button according to its "booked" status ("booked" or "not booked")

Comment: Thanks! I will try this tomorrow..makes sense and hopefully it will work, but I have been sitting here for 5 hours and getting kinda tired. Thanks alot!

Comment: No problem, if you have more questions tomorrow, just comment here and we can continue.

Comment: Not sure how to use change `<asp:TableCell ... CssClass=bookedButton>` in behind the code c# on page load. And if it's possible I don't want to change everybutton 1 by 1. I want all of them connected to a control of some sort.

EDIT kinda like `Button myButton = sender as Button`

Comment: If you want any styling to happen when the page loads, you would have to assign some unique value to each TableCell on the server side, before your code gets rendered to HTML, or run though each TableCell after the page loads and apply the styling then. I can't think of a way to avoid applying unique styles to specific buttons without a way to first identify the "unique" buttons. Meaning, if you want to style something as "booked", you first need to somehow "tag" or "label" that button as "booked", and in your case, the server side seems more efficient (my option #1);

Comment: Sure but it still dont understand how I can change my HTML style in c#.. I can't accsess my HTML controlls from c# that is `if(booked = true){change the css style on <asp:button>}` since I can't accsess <asp:Button> from c#


EDIT Oh you mean that I should create the table from server side, and not direkt from html?

Comment: Yeah, you want to create the table on the server, so your server-side code is asking "is this button booked or not?", and if its booked add the class "isBooked" and if its not booked add the class "button". Then, your css can apply the `.isBooked` or `.button` classes appropriately.